# Unruly Child Dialogue, C# .Net Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using WinForms for a C# project and my main form has a simple button that uses ShowDialog(this) on a second form to show it.
Like this:

```
if (myParameterForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {//stuff happens}
```

As per my requirements, when the child form is visible, you cannot access the parent form.

For the past year this child form has been the bane of my application as it mysteriously manages to hide behind its parent form from time to time. The reason this is such a big problem is because the software is designed to be used from a touchscreen kiosk, so the user only has access to a touch-screen, but the child form has locked input from any form but itself till it is acknowledged (closed with ok or cancel).

On load the child form uses "this.TopMost = true" just in case, I added this as an effort to fix my problem.
I use no other visualizing functions on the child form, the thread calling the form literally waits there till the form is closed.

Since the user has no access to a keyboard, or anything but a touchscreen I'm miffed as to how the child form manages to hide behind the parent form. I actually have been unable to replicate the behavior, and have only seen it as a result of responding to service requests.

I want to avoid using a timer to continually check if the form is TopMost because it just seems wrong. Should I reconsider? What event could possibly be occurring that is banishing my child form backstage?

I've tried using the search, but as far as I can tell I'm doing this correctly... Assuming that there is some sinister 3rd party application causing occasional hijinks, what is the best way to detect and rectify this situation automatically without throwing in a periodic check? I am not sure that the VisibleChanged event is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Dialog forms just don't work like that.  You have something else going on that you aren't showing.

Comment: How do you know the form is behind the main form and not closed altogether? Just wondering.

Comment: @rsbarro: I know it's behind because if I attach a keyboard, hit WinKey, I can just click on it in the taskbar, and it'll just go back to the front. For the users... it's impossible to know what's wrong, as far as they are concerned it looks like the mouse just refuses to click.

Comment: @LarsTech: That's why I'm confused. There could be lots of things going on. User have their own admins with remote access/control, anti-virus, whatnot. I'm not at all controlling the form's visibility after it loads till it closes.

Comment: When you say click it, does the child window show in the taskbar, or is it just the application that's showing. Have you tried setting the `ShowInTaskbar` property to false on the child form?

Comment: @rsbarro: it shows in the task bar. Should I not show it in the task bar? If I don't do that I imagine it'll be a lot harder for me to get it back to the foreground.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior you are describing by minimizing the child window. Is it possible that something is minimizing the window? Has you tried disabling the control box for the dialog?

Comment: @rsbarro - My goodness I'm such a newbie. The control box is still there! How did I miss that over all this time? Please put an answer in so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce the behavior you are describing by minimizing the child window when it is displayed using `ShowDialog`. Is it possible that something is minimizing the child window? You could try disabling the control box for the child window to see if that helps. I would probably also set `ShowInTaskbar` to false for the child window (for usability reasons).

Comment: I can't believe I missed that all this time. This solves the root of my problem. I almost deleted my question when I saw how blind I was! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just implement the child form as a dynamically loaded user control instead. When you need it just load it on top of everything else. This way your main window is always in focus and the content you want to display is on top. this will obviously be a bit of work, but judging by the fact that this has been a problem for a year, you probably don't mind the work if it fixes the problem. There may be more intricacies that you'll have to deal with(i.e. having to make all other controls invisible until the child is done, etc.) but I think this is the easiest and most reliable fix.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean load it as part of the main form instead of having it actually be its own form?

Comment: Yes that would be my suggestion. Then you will not have to juggle to windows at all. Like I said though, it will be a bit more work.

Comment: Actually, that would be less work, because I have to pass datatables to that window and it's been pretty clumsy work. I suppose I can make a mystic groupbox that appears and disappears as I need it. Cool suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience TopMost windows and modal dialogs never behave very well ... as you can lock yourself out if a TopMost window happen to cover the modal dialog control. Are you applying TopMost to the main window anywhere in your code?

Comment: My main form never uses TopMost, only that single child form uses it, and it was only put in when I responded to the first time the child form went missing. So in my entire project "TopMost" only appears once.

Comment: what happens if you click on the main window while the "modal" dialog is "hidden"?